# JMeter NTLM, which request should be included?

Tags: jmeter, ntlm

I am using JMeter to automate a site that involves NTLM authentication.

I have recorded the traffic and identified three main requests with below Response Headers:

**1st request:**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
```

**2nd request:**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate + authentication token
```

**3rd request:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

My question is, which request should I keep in my test plan and which requests should I remove, considering that JMeter Authorization Manager seems to be able to handle the process of NTLM.

I have read many blogs related to JMeter and NTLM but I have not seen any reference to this particular question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Given you properly configure [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager), to wit provide:

- **Username**
- **Password**
- **Domain**
- and optionally **Realm**

You should leave only one request, HTTP Authorization Manager will automatically construct proper [Authorization Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) which should let you in.

See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article for more details.